# Frame in screen on UIView who is in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I would to know if there are an easy way to get the frame in the main screen of a UIView who is in a UIScrollview.

Like - rectForRowAtIndexPath: in a UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check UIView documentation
[`convertRect:fromView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect:fromView:)

Rect argument should be frame of your UIView, from view is your UIScrollView

Next time consider reading documentation before asking

Comment: If my view have for x 20 and for y 500 and the scrollview scroll down from 200 pixel I want to get x=20 and y=300 and not 500

Comment: Method in my answer will do exactly what you want